# get only last record based on ids

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am building chat app and I want to display only last record as per users
Like I have sent 1000s message but I have only chatted with 10 people then I need to get the name of 10 people and last message whether they sent me or I sent them at last

[image]

Please see above table and give me solution like I want to get only one record from the last two records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where created = (
    select max(created)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.m_from = t.m_from and t1.m_to = t.m_to
)
```

This will give you only the latest message for each `(m_from, m_to)` tuple (according to the date stored in column `created`).

If you want the latest message per `(m_from, m_to)` *or* `(m_to, m_from)`, then:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where created = (
    select max(created)
    from mytable t1
    where 
        (t1.m_from = t.m_from and t1.m_to = t.m_to)
        or (t1.m_from = t.m_to and t1.m_to = t.m_from)
)
```

Comment: Asumming that `created` foreach `m_from, m_to` combination can not have duplicaties in the `created` column this would indeed should give the lastest message record per combination otherwise it is not that clear which record would be the max where `created` values tie.. When in doubt those datetimes can be altered as `datetime(6)` instead making that window smaller no nobody could type that fast unless you are superman offcource :-)....